# Calculating MD5 of Hex in Python

Tags: python, encryption, hash, md5

I always fail with the decrypting of a RC4 encrypted object. My key has to be the MD5-Hash of this hex string:

```
00 00 00 01 3e 2a 5b 71 00 00 03 a0
```

What i tried was to convert that hex string to ascii and calculate afterwards the MD5 hash of it, but it seems like my key is always wrong. I think there is a problem because some of the hex values are control characters, but how is then the correct way to calculate the MD5 of this hex string ? What i thought of was something like this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
from Crypto.Hash import MD5


def hexToAscii(hex_string):
    return ''.join([chr(int(''.join(c), 16)) for c in zip(hex_string[0::2],hex_string[1::2])])

def main():
    hex_string = '000000013e2a5b71000003a0'

    # Key for Decryption
    myKey = MD5.new(hexToAscii(hex_string)).hexdigest()

    print 'hexToAscii(hex_string): %s' % hexToAscii(hex_string)

    #open('myfile','wb').write(ARC4.new(hexToAscii(myKey)).decrypt(hexToAscii(CIPHER_TEXT)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` function prints `hexToAscii(hex_string)` instead of `myKey`.

BTW, you'd better to use [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) instead of `hexToAscii`. And you can use [`hashlib` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) to calculate md5.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import binascii
>>> hex_string = '000000013e2a5b71000003a0'
>>> hashlib.md5(binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)).hexdigest()
'6afebf522c531575e96d6814be816c7c'
```

Comment: Yes i deliberately wanted to print hexToAscii(hex_string) in main because i thought that it might be problematic to calculate the md5 of an ascii where control characters are converted to "???". I just wanted to see what the ascii output of this hex_string is going to be. Because when i convert that hex_string i get ">*[q�" and calculating the md5 out of that and using it as my key to decrypt my RC4 object still gives me a corrupt output. But i think the key must me right and the problem of decryption might be somewhere else.

Comment: @Caffeine, What result to be written to the file? (And what is the `CIPHER_TEXT` value?)

Comment: The result of the ARC4 decrypted Cipher Text. So this one: open('output.dll','wb').write(ARC4.new(key).decrypt(binascii.unhexlify(Cipher_Text))) whereby the key should be the md5 you calculated above. I do so, but get always a corrupt dll file so i thought calculating the md5 of ">*[q�" would be the reason why ?

Comment: @Caffeine, What is the value of the `CIPHER_TEXT`?

Comment: @Caffeine, It would be good if you provide correct original `dll` and encrypted `dll`.

Comment: @Caffeine, Do you the md5 of the original dll?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the question. This DLL is all i got and what i know is that it is RC4 encrypted with the key being the md5 of hex_string, or did i misunderstand you ?

Comment: @Caffeine, I mean: If I decrypt it, how can I confirm it was successfully decrypted?

Answer (score 0):

Use `hashlib` and `binascii` from Python standard lib, no conversion to ASCII involved:

```
import binascii
import hashlib

base = binascii.unhexlify("000000013e2a5b71000003a0")
key = hashlib.md5(base).digest()
```